# BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default. This is no longer the case

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I know there are several answers to this problem already, but none of them have worked for me.

I already installed these packages:

- mysql
- buffer
- crypto-browserify
- utils
- process

And my webpack.config.js file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  resolve:
      {fallback:
          {
            "crypto": false,
            "stream": false,
            "timers": false
          }
      }
}
```

I have also tried the webpack.config.js file to look like this:

```
module.exports = {
    resolve:
        {fallback:
            {
                "timers": require.resolve("timers-browserify"),
                "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
                "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify")
            }
        }

}
```

The line of code that calls mysql just looks like this (this line alone initiates the errors):

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
```

And this is what the error says:

> Compiled with problems:
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js 1:13-30
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in
> '/home/pattmayne/Prog/robotblog/robot-god-blog/node_modules/mysql/lib'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
> - install 'crypto-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:   resolve.fallback: {
>   "crypto": false }
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js 3:10-24
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in
> '/home/pattmayne/Prog/robotblog/robot-god-blog/node_modules/mysql/lib'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js 4:10-24
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in
> '/home/pattmayne/Prog/robotblog/robot-god-blog/node_modules/mysql/lib'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Auth.js 2:13-30
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in
> '/home/pattmayne/Prog/robotblog/robot-god-blog/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
> - install 'crypto-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:   resolve.fallback: {
>   "crypto": false }
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js 4:13-37
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in
> '/home/pattmayne/Prog/robotblog/robot-god-blog/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
> - install 'stream-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:   resolve.fallback: {
>   "stream": false }
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Timer.js 1:13-30
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'timers' in
> '/home/pattmayne/Prog/robotblog/robot-god-blog/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "timers": require.resolve("timers-browserify") }'
> - install 'timers-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:   resolve.fallback: {
>   "timers": false }
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js 2:9-22
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> '/home/pattmayne/Prog/robotblog/robot-god-blog/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences'

Did I install something wrong?